# Два массива: есть ли разница в инициализации и удалении?

Tags: c++, массивы, объявление

Изучаю C++. Нужны большие массивы. Хочу понять, есть ли разница в инициализации и удалении (скорость важнее, но также важно, чтобы не было проблем) между:

```
int sequence[1000000];
```

и

```
std::array<int, 1000000> sequence;
```

Или вообще нет разницы?

**Update 1**

Получается, чтобы не было проблем со стеком, я должен поступать как-то так:

```
auto sequence = std::make_unique<int[]>(1000000);
```

И тогда массив будет создаваться в динамической памяти?

Comment: в целом на максимальной оптимизации разницы нету. `std::array` это тонкий враппер над обычным массивом.

Comment: Особой разница нет, std::array просто обёртка над сишными массивами, но в любом случае не стеке создавать ни то ни другое с такими размерами не стоит...

Comment: @Fat-Zer А если линкеру выдать команду  /STACK:40000000000 ?

Comment: А почему нельзя просто использовать new и оставить стек в задаче про большие данные в покое?

Comment: @wirtwelt можно. Но есть дурацкая привычка докапываться, почему это так, а не иначе

Comment: Хорошая привычка, добавил ответ

Comment: @ViktorTomilov, вообще говоря, про неограниченный стек интересный вопрос... на x86 понятно, что его в итоге может не хватить, а вот на amd64 я вижу только один аргумент против оного: в случае нетерменированной рекурсии придётся ждать полного исчерпания физической памяти и подкачки прежде чем процесс будет убит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оба ваших варианта создают обычный массив (указатель) на 1000000 элементов типа `int`

Однако они это делают в стеке (stack), временной памяти конкретной функции. Если вам нужно эти данные не только создать, но и обработать, и скорее всего - в нескольких функциях, то разумнее использовать динамическую память (heap)

Чтобы создавать массивы в динамической памяти, используйте конструкции new, а лучше STL:

```
std::vector<int> dynamic_array;
```

Такой "массив" будет хранить все ваши `int` в динамической памяти, но сама переменная будет создана там, где вы ее создадите. Если это будет в функции - при выходе из функции (за границу видимости) переменная и все ее содержимое уничтожится автоматически. Варианты: глобальная переменная, поле глобального класса или везде таскать указатель на эту переменную созданную через `new`, смотря как у вас спроектирован проект

Если вас интересует скорость, вы можете сэкономить время на изменении размера области памяти под хранение элементов (при помещении элементов в std::vector он автоматически разрастается в памяти), сразу вызвав [resize(N)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/) с известным вам заранее размером массива

Работать с вектором можно так же, как с обычным массивом, через [std::vector[]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator[]/):

```
dynamic_array.resize(100);
dynamic_array[11] = 5;
dynamic_array[10] = dynamic_array[11];
std::cout << dynamic_array[10] << std::endl;
```

Если для вас крайне важна скорость, динамическую память можно задействовать и проще:

```
int *sequence = new int[1000000];
if (sequence) { // Можно не проверять, new по умолчанию кидает исключение при неудаче
    /* Производите всю необходимую работу */
    delete [] sequence;
    sequence = NULL;
}
```

Не факт, что простая работа с указателем даст значительный выигрыш по времени, но обертка std::vector в итоге делает именно это + некую обертку и дополнительные проверки. Однако в данном случае всю заботу о содержимом и о занятой памяти вы должны будете взять на себя. Но вы программист Си, вы крепкий, справитесь ) Кто же кроме нас.. )

Comment: Си я изучал очень давно :) С тех пор студентам преподавал (не как информатик, а как прикладник), в основном, Delphi. Кстати, C++, на мой взгляд (и пусть меня закидают тапками :)), больше похож на Delphi, нежели на Си.